# Find $\displaystyle \min_{f \in \mathcal{A}} \int_{0}^{1} (1+x^{2})(f(x))^{2} dx $

Tags: real-analysis

Find $$ \min_{f \in \mathcal{A}} \int_{0}^{1} (1+x^{2})(f(x))^{2} dx $$
where $$ \mathcal{A}=\left\{ f \in C[a,b] \ | \ \int_{0}^{1} f(x) dx = 1 \right\}.$$

I used the Hölder's inequality to try to solve the problem but I do not know how to reduce the term with $(f (x))^{4}$, i.e, $$\int_{0}^{1} (1+x^{2})(f(x))^{2} dx 
 \leq \left( \int_{0}^{1} (1+x^{2})dx \right)^{\frac{1}{2}} \left(  \int_{0}^{1} (f(x))^{4} dx \right)^{\frac{1}{2}} $$
I appreciate any help.

Comment: Possibly some sort of calculus of variations required?

Comment: By the Lagrange multiplier rule I get $f(x)=\frac{4}{\pi}\frac{1}{1+x^2}$ as a possible minimizer.

Comment: The Hölders inequality is giving an upper bound, so won't tell you the minimum value.

Answer (score 8):

We have
$$
1=\int_0^1 f(x)dx = \int_0^1 \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^2}} (\sqrt{1+x^2} f(x))dx
$$
$$
\le  \left(\int_0^1 \frac{1}{1+x^2} dx \right)^{1/2} \left(\int_0^1 (1+x^2) (f(x))^2 dx\right)^{1/2}
$$
$$
=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{4}} \left(\int_0^1 (1+x^2) (f(x))^2 dx\right)^{1/2}.
$$
Thus
$$
\frac{4}{\pi} \le \int_0^1 (1+x^2) (f(x))^2 dx.
$$
For $f_{min}(x):= \frac{4}{\pi} \frac{1}{1+x^2}$ we have
$$
\int_0^1f_{min}(x) dx=1, \quad \int_0^1 (1+x^2) (f_{min}(x))^2 dx = \frac{4}{\pi}.
$$
Thus the minimum is $4/\pi$.